# Update and append decoded JSON into struct?

Tags: swift, decoding, swift-structs

I'm receiving some paginated JSON response through my API that looks something like this:

page 1:

```
{
    "count": 96,
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/id=5/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 10,
            "book_name": "Book name",
            "book_id": 70,
            "chapter_number": 1,
            "verse": "Verse title here",
            "verse_number": 1,
            "chapter": 96
        },
        {
            "id": 198,
            "book_name": "Book Name",
            "book_id": 70,
            "chapter_number": 8,
            "verse": "Text here",
            "verse_number": 5,
            "chapter": 103
        }
    ]
}
```

As I move through the paginated result, ie calling: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/id=5/?page=2`
I'll get new values in the `results` array.

page 2:

```
{
    "count": 96,
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/id=5/?page=3",
    "previous": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/id=5/",
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 206,
            "book_name": "Book on Second page",
            "book_id": 70,
            "chapter_number": 8,
            "verse": "yadda yadda",
            "verse_number": 13,
            "chapter": 103
        },
        {
            "id": 382,
            "book_name": "Book on second page..",
            "book_id": 70,
            "chapter_number": 15,
            "verse": "Verse here",
            "verse_number": 12,
            "chapter": 110
        }
    ]
}
```

How would I structure my struct/fix my decoding so I can append the values of `results` from the JSON while still updating `count`, `next` and `previous` as I go through `..?page=3`, `..?page=4` etc

Currently, my struct looks like this:

```
struct VersesSearchResult: Decodable {
    var results: [Verse]
    var count: Int
    var next: String?
    var previous: String?
}
```

When doing the decoding, I'm not sure what the syntax should be like to *append* results to the struct, and *update* `next`, `previous`, and `count`. So far I got this

```
...
let verses = try JSONDecoder().decode(VersesSearchResult, from: safeData)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // somehow need to get this to work - not entirely sure how
    // where results gets appended, while the rest in the JSON values gets updated
   // obviously I can't do as below:
    self.verseSearchResult.append(contentsOf: verses.results)
    self.verseSearchResult = verses
}
...
```

Comment: That was just an unfinished example - not sure how to proceed. If you're referring to the `let verses = .....` part.

I'm not doing anything in there right now - just wanted to display some information to make it clear what it is I wish to achieve

Comment: What is unclear?

Comment: I don't know how it can be unclear. Frankly, I'm unclear as to what you think is unclear. Do you need the boilerplate code for making the API call?

Comment: Not offended at all! Just trying to understand how I can make it more clear and perhaps update the original question

Comment: Well, the idea is that only part of the JSON should be appended, more specifically, the `results` part. I don't want to re-append `count`, `next` and `previous`. That part should just be "overwritten" so to say. 

Here's a gist with the struct(s) and the API call itself: https://gist.github.com/erikvlm/237a8668f58d82df3e855fecb1d42d74

My "hack" is that I decode two separate structs in the same API call now, not sure if its the best way though

Comment: Sure, that works, but what about the `count`, `next` and `previous`? Where should I store that. The whole `(self.verseSearchResult.append(contentsOf: verses.results))` part would only take care of the `results` array from the json

Comment: Okay, well, I did write the following:

How would I structure my struct/fix my decoding so I can append the values of results from the JSON while still updating count, next and previous as I go through ..?page=3, ..?page=4 etc

Answer (score 0):

Decode to a temprary instance of the type, then process those properties into your main instance.  Depending how you want to process the data, it'll look something like this

```
extension VersesSearchResult {

  mutating func update(with new: VersesSearchResult) {
    results.append(new)
    count = new.count
    next = new.next
    prev = new.prev
  }
}
```

and then in your completion block

```
let newVerses = try JSONDecoder().decode(VersesSearchResult, from: safeData)
self.verses.update(with: newVerses)
```

If needs be force the update onto the main thread.

You should also handle failure in the 'try' either with a `do...catch` or other approach.

Comment: I ended up doing something like this: https://gist.github.com/erikvlm/237a8668f58d82df3e855fecb1d42d74

Where I just decode two structs in one api call - not sure if this is an ugly hack or bad practice to use the JSONDecoder() twice?